# passing multiple array to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created my model to be a multiple array myArr[10,10].
Then I want that model to be returned to my view and I want to be able to check what values are in the array.

My code:
model

```
  public class MapModel
{
    private int[,] mapTilesArray = new int[10, 10];

    public int[,] MapTilesArray
    {
        get { return mapTilesArray; }
        set
        {
           mapTilesArray = value;
        }

    }

    public MapModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                mapTilesArray[i, j] = 1;
            };
    }
```

controler

```
   public MapModel mapModel = new MapModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var map = mapModel.MapTilesArray;

        return View(map);
    }
```

view

```
  @model GraAjaxTeamProject.Models.MapModel

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }


 @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
<div>
@for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
  if (Model.MapTilesArray[i,j] == 1)
{
     <div style="height:30px;width:30px;border:1px solid gray;background-color:red;display:inline-block;"></div>
}  


}
</div>
 }
```

when I run this i have error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32[,]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'GraAjaxTeamProject.Models.MapModel'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the MapModel to your view. Either change @model to `int[,]` or remove `.MapTilesArray` from your call to view.

From the example given in your view, you should be changing the lines

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var map = mapModel.MapTilesArray;

    return View(map);
}
```

To

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(mapModel);
}
```